# Google Chrome - IndexedDB - Quota

Tags: google-chrome, indexeddb

What are the quota limitations of indexedDB in google chrome? Somehow, there seems to be very little mentioned on this out there. Can I use unlimited quota with user permission like in firefox?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988569/what-are-the-storage-limits-for-the-indexed-db-on-googles-chrome-browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlimited wasn't talked about in that other question, but you can read about it here:
https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage#unlimited

The short version is that you can request unlimited indexeddb storage for an app or extension, but not a normal page.