# How to detect that IndexedDB's storage limit has been reached?

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

How can one detect via the JavaScript IndexedDB API that the storage limit is reached? I envision that when trying to write data to the DB one can be notified that there's no more room?

Comment: Solution mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988569/what-are-the-storage-limits-for-the-indexed-db-on-googles-chrome-browser) should help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome will put "QuotaExceededError" in `event.target.error.name` for the error callback. I'm not sure if this is done by other browsers, though.

Comment: I think that only gets filled in for the transaction's abort callback, not the error callback. Though I am not positive.

Comment: Either  way, I guess it's through an error callback. That'll have to do I suppose, catch it like a general error.

Answer (score -1):

Storage limits

There isn't any limit on a single database item's size. However there may be a limit on each IndexedDB database's size. This limit (and the way the user interface will assert it) may vary from one browser to another:

```
Firefox: no limit on the IndexedDB database's size. The user interface will just ask permission for storing blobs bigger than 50 MB. This size quota can be customized through the dom.indexedDB.warningQuota preference (which is defined in http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/modules/libpref/src/init/all.js).
Google Chrome: see https://developers.google.com/chrome...rage#temporary
```