# Detecting Available Storage with IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I have written an offline application that utilises IDB to store images and text that would normally exist in a MySQL DB for offline use.

However, I am trying to figure out a way that I can read the limit on the devices storage for IndexedDB. I am currently using the following method to determine this although it only works in Chrome.

I am using the snippet from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18350531/4121257 which gets the `storageInfo` for WebKit based however if someone knows a way to get it on FF & IE & more specifically Safari that would be great.

From what I have gathered this returns the used quota for everything stored by that browser for the domain not just IDB. However, what I am using is the remaning quota. From this I either perform an AJAX request to the server to get the estimated size of all the files that will be stored and work out if there is enough storage or I will calculate the ammount stored in the IDB and work out if there is enough to store more.

I was wondering if someone had a more 'streamlined' approach?  And a way to check the remaning quota in FF/IE and especially Safari & even a way to check quota for IDB specifically.

Comment: See [Browser storage limits and eviction criteria](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria)

Comment: This question is a bit confused; you say that your current approach only works for WebKit-based browsers, then ask how to make it work for Safari... but Safari *is* WebKit-based!

Answer (score 15):

The only API that is currently available and only for chrome is `navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage.queryUsageAndQuota()`.

Firefox [had plans](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2014JanMar/0140.html) to implement this API too.

There are also two experimental APIs `navigator.storageQuota.queryInfo(type)` and `navigator.storage.estimate()` available if you run chrome with `--enable-experimental-web-platform-features`. More details here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!searchin/blink-dev/quota-api/blink-dev/P6eY26vB91c/Ri4ohXOPBQAJ

I think the [Storage quota estimate() API](https://storage.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-storagemanager-estimate) is the most interesting one. It is still a draft but [chrome](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5630353511284736) and [mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1267941) are currently implementing this API.

Unfortunately there is currently no public info available when and if [Edge](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/15632454-storage-quota-estimate-api) and Safari will implement this API.

> Edge currently has a very different model for quota - rather than a whole-origin limit, each storage type (indexed db, local storage, etc) has its own limit.

**Update:** This feature was added to Chrome 52 (experimental flag) and Firefox 51 (nightly)
`navigator.storage.estimate().then((data)=>console.log(data)) // Object { quota: 2147483648, usage: 0 }`

Comment: Currently Firefox support for [`navigator.storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorStorage/storage) is disable by `dom.storageManager.enabled`, except in Nightly versions. [Nightly 55 also makes it https only](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1268804).