# Property 'webkitTemporaryStorage' does not exist on type 'Navigator'

Tags: typescript, indexeddb

I am using below code to check size of **indexeddb**

```
navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage.queryUsageAndQuota ( 
function(usedBytes, grantedBytes) {  
    console.log('we are using ', usedBytes, ' of ', grantedBytes, 'bytes');
}, 
function(e) { console.log('Error', e);  }
);
```

But got error like Property `webkitTemporaryStorage` does not exist on type `Navigator`.

I am new to angular. can anyone pls help me solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this isn't issue of `Angular`, it's about browser. Well it's looks like it will only work for chrome. Here is right [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38905723/4700863) for that.

Comment: thanks.I tried that navigator.storage.estimate() already.For that I am getting "[ts] Property 'storage' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.
any" error in typescript

Comment: It is solved by                                                                                           let nav: any = navigator;

   nav.webkitTemporaryStorage.queryUsageAndQuota ( 
     function(usedBytes, grantedBytes) {  
     console.log('we are using ', usedBytes, ' of ', grantedBytes, 'bytes');
  }, 
     function(e) { console.log('Error', e);  }
 );

Answer (score 0):

Better view of @kamalav answer (see his comment on other answer) :

```
const nav: any = navigator;
nav.webkitTemporaryStorage.queryUsageAndQuota ( (usedBytes, grantedBytes) => {
    console.log('we are using ', usedBytes, ' of ', grantedBytes, 'bytes');
}, (e) => {
    console.log('Error', e);
});
```

The solution is to define navigator property as any and problem is fixed